# How can I make a "show up" text animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve the kind of behavior shown in the material.io page:

[image]

The text does a nice transition when is being shown for the first time.

How can I do that in Flutter?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can compose widgets like this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowUp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int delay;

  ShowUp({@required this.child, this.delay});

  @override
  _ShowUpState createState() => _ShowUpState();
}

class _ShowUpState extends State<ShowUp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animController;
  Animation<Offset> _animOffset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    final curve =
        CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _animController);
    _animOffset =
        Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.35), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(curve);

    if (widget.delay == null) {
      _animController.forward();
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
        _animController.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animOffset,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      opacity: _animController,
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
int delayAmount = 500;
...........
...........
...........
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            ShowUp(
              child: Text("The first texto to be shown"),
              delay: delayAmount,
            ),

            ShowUp(
              child: Text("The text below the first"),
              delay: delayAmount + 200,
            ),

            ShowUp(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Texts together 1"),
                  Text("Texts together 2"),
                  Text("Texts together 3"),
                ],
              ),
              delay: delayAmount + 400,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

**Note that this "ShowUp" widgets can animate anything, not just texts.**

Comment: This is really a helpful implementation if we want to add animation to our app. Simply we can make separate widgets like this to pass Child WIdget and delay so we can have great animation in our app.

Answer (score 6):

There's an existing package called [show_up_animation](https://pub.dev/packages/show_up_animation/) for it which is based on the implementation below.

This is a generalized widget to provide this animation. All you have to do is to wrap your widget(yes, any widget) inside SlideFadeTransition widget and voila!

It gives a lot of control. For example, you can control the amount, speed, direction, delay and even the curve of the animation.

```
///Wrapper class to implement slide and fade animations at the same time to
///a given element. Wrap the widget that you wish to appear with slide-fade
///transition in this class.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum Direction { vertical, horizontal }

class SlideFadeTransition extends StatefulWidget {
  ///The child on which to apply the given [SlideFadeTransition]
  final Widget child;

  ///The offset by which to slide and [child] into view from [Direction].
  ///Defaults to 0.2
  final double offset;

  ///The curve used to animate the [child] into view.
  ///Defaults to [Curves.easeIn]
  final Curve curve;

  ///The direction from which to animate the [child] into view. [Direction.horizontal]
  ///will make the child slide on x-axis by [offset] and [Direction.vertical] on y-axis.
  ///Defaults to [Direction.vertical]
  final Direction direction;

  ///The delay with which to animate the [child]. Takes in a [Duration] and
  /// defaults to 0.0 seconds
  final Duration delayStart;

  ///The total duration in which the animation completes. Defaults to 800 milliseconds
  final Duration animationDuration;

  SlideFadeTransition({
    @required this.child,
    this.offset = 0.2,
    this.curve = Curves.easeIn,
    this.direction = Direction.vertical,
    this.delayStart = const Duration(seconds: 0),
    this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  });
  @override
  _SlideFadeTransitionState createState() => _SlideFadeTransitionState();
}

class _SlideFadeTransitionState extends State<SlideFadeTransition>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<Offset> _animationSlide;

  AnimationController _animationController;

  Animation<double> _animationFade;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: widget.animationDuration,
    );

    //configure the animation controller as per the direction
    if (widget.direction == Direction.vertical) {
      _animationSlide =
          Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, widget.offset), end: Offset(0, 0))
              .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        curve: widget.curve,
        parent: _animationController,
      ));
    } else {
      _animationSlide =
          Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(widget.offset, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
              .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        curve: widget.curve,
        parent: _animationController,
      ));
    }

    _animationFade =
        Tween<double>(begin: -1.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: widget.curve,
      parent: _animationController,
    ));

    Timer(widget.delayStart, () {
      _animationController.forward();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animationFade,
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animationSlide,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To use it, you just have to wrap your text widget or any widget for that matter with SlideFadeTransition widget. Below is a complete working example.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Show up Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Show up Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SlideFadeTransition(
              child: Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
            ),
            SlideFadeTransition(
              delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
              child: Text(
                '0',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {});
        },
        tooltip: 'Animate',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

///Wrapper class to implement slide and fade animations at the same time to
///a given element. Wrap the widget that you wish to appear with slide-fade
///transition in this class.

enum Direction { vertical, horizontal }

class SlideFadeTransition extends StatefulWidget {
  ///The child on which to apply the given [SlideFadeTransition]
  final Widget child;

  ///The offset by which to slide and [child] into view from [Direction].
  ///Defaults to 1.0
  final double offset;

  ///The curve used to animate the [child] into view.
  ///Defaults to [Curves.easeIn]
  final Curve curve;

  ///The direction from which to animate the [child] into view. [Direction.horizontal]
  ///will make the child slide on x-axis by [offset] and [Direction.vertical] on y-axis.
  ///Defaults to [Direction.vertical]
  final Direction direction;

  ///The delay with which to animate the [child]. Takes in a [Duration] and
  /// defaults to 0.0 seconds
  final Duration delayStart;

  ///The total duration in which the animation completes. Defaults to 800 milliseconds
  final Duration animationDuration;

  SlideFadeTransition({
    @required this.child,
    this.offset = 1.0,
    this.curve = Curves.easeIn,
    this.direction = Direction.vertical,
    this.delayStart = const Duration(seconds: 0),
    this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  });
  @override
  _SlideFadeTransitionState createState() => _SlideFadeTransitionState();
}

class _SlideFadeTransitionState extends State<SlideFadeTransition>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<Offset> _animationSlide;

  AnimationController _animationController;

  Animation<double> _animationFade;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: widget.animationDuration,
    );

    //configure the animation controller as per the direction
    if (widget.direction == Direction.vertical) {
      _animationSlide =
          Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, widget.offset), end: Offset(0, 0))
              .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        curve: widget.curve,
        parent: _animationController,
      ));
    } else {
      _animationSlide =
          Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(widget.offset, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
              .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        curve: widget.curve,
        parent: _animationController,
      ));
    }

    _animationFade =
        Tween<double>(begin: -1.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: widget.curve,
      parent: _animationController,
    ));

    Timer(widget.delayStart, () {
      _animationController.forward();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animationFade,
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animationSlide,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Gif]

Answer (score 2):

I built a package to do this simply.
[delayed_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/delayed_widget)

```
Example:
     DelayedWidget(            
            delayDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),// Not required
            animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),// Not required
              animation: DelayedAnimations.SLIDE_FROM_BOTTOM,// Not required
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.red,
          ))
```